# add extra field woocommerce checkout out

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

im attempting to add an extra field to the woocommerce place order button using

```
/**
 * Add PO checkout field 
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'invoice_po' );
function invoice_po($checkout)
    { 
    woocommerce_form_field('invoice_po_field', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array(
            'form-row-wide') ,
            'label' => __('Invoice Customer PO') ,
            'placeholder' => __('PO123456789') ,
            'required' => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('invoice_po_field'));
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_po_to_order_meta');
function add_po_to_order_meta($order_id)
{
  if (!empty($_POST['invoice_po_field'])) {
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'Invoice Field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['invoice_po_field']));
  }
}
```

this method works fine if i want to add it before or after order notes but will not work if attempting to add before place order button does any one know why i cant add a field on in this section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with my code was ($checkout) this variable is only relevant to the address and customer notes section of the checkout page to allow access to all page hooks i just removed it

```
/**
 * Add PO checkout field 
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'invoice_po');
function invoice_po()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('invoice_customer', $user->roles)) {
        woocommerce_form_field('invoice_po_field', array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => array('form-row-wide') ,
            'label' => __('Invoice Customer PO') ,
            'placeholder' => __('PO123456789') ,
            'required' => true
        ));
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_po_to_order_meta');
function add_po_to_order_meta($order_id)
{
  if (!empty($_POST['invoice_po_field'])) {
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'Invoice Field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['invoice_po_field']));
  }
}
```